# How does extract() create variables in the current scope?

Tags: php, variables, extract

I'm curious, how does the PHP's function [extract](http://php.net/extract) do it's work? I would like to make a slightly modified version. I want my function to make the variable names when extracting from the keys of the array from snake notation to camelCase e.g:

Now extract does this:

```
$array = ['foo_bar' => 'baz'];
extract($array);
// $foo_bar = 'baz';
```

What I would like is:

```
camelExtract($array);
// $fooBar = 'baz';
```

Now I could of course camelCase the array first, but it would be nice if this could be done in a single function.

edit:

It seems some people misread my question. Yes I could do this:

```
function camelExtract($array)
{
    $array = ['foo_bar' => 'baz'];
    $camelCased = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        $camelCased[camelcase($key)] = $val;
    }
    extract($camelCased);
    // $fooBar = 'baz';


    // I can't "return" the extracted variables here 
    // .. now $fooBar is only available in this scope
}

camelExtract($array);
// Not here
```

But as I've stated, then the $fooBar is only visible within that scope.

I guess I could do something as `extract(camelCaseArray($array));` and that would work.

Comment: So make your own function to do this

Comment: Yes, but how can I 'magically' create variables in the current scope like that function?

Comment: its not magic, its code

Comment: Start your function with the loop to camcel case the array kets then call extrat() at the end. That's all there is to it.

Comment: That was metaphorical. I don't know how in PHP I can "spawn" variables from array keys just like extract does. Give me a push in the right direction then. I must be missing something plain obvious, since the comments are a little bit degrading.

Comment: And that Jon Conde, is exactly what I stated what I could do, but did not want to do. I wanted to do it in one function. - Then you might think, write the loop to camelCase in the function. But then the variables are only visible in that function. Which is not the case with extract.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. There's a uniqueness to extract() in that it's able somehow to get a handle to the current scope and manipulate it without explicit assignments. Sorry, I don't know of any other function that does that, or how to connect your own function to that capability without wrapping it in extract. There are get_defined_vars and compact which are related but I don't think they help you.

Comment: I mean I think it's probably not a good idea for maintainability to make variables magically appear in your scope, with extract or otherwise, but it is an interesting point as to the uniqueness of extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), and modification to the *callees* local symbol table from within a *called* function is magic. There is no way to perform the equivalent in plain-PHP without using it.

The final task can be solved using John Conde's suggesting of using `extra` *after* performing a transformation to the supplied array keys; although my recommendation is to *avoid* extract-like behavior entirely. The approach would then look similar to

```
extract(camelcase_keys($arr));
```

where such code is *not* wrapped in a function so that `extract` is executed from the scope of the symbol table in which to import the variables.

---

This `extract` behavior is is *unlike* variable-variables (in a called function) and is *unlike* using $GLOBALS as it mutates the callees (and *only* the callees) symbol table as see [seen in this demo](http://ideone.com/XnaEKi):

```
function extract_container () {
    extract(array("foo" => "bar"));
    return $foo;
}

echo "Extract: " . extract_container() . "\n";  // "bar" =>
echo "Current: " . $foo . "\n";                 //       => {no $foo in scope}
echo "Global:  " . $GLOBALS['foo'] . "\n";      //       => {no 'foo' in GLOBALS}
```

The C implementation for `extract` can be found in [ext/standard/array.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c). This behavior is allowed because the native function does *not* create a new/local PHP symbol table for itself; as such it is allowed to (trivially) modify the symbol table of the calling PHP context.

Comment: There is no way: Except for the other answer.

Comment: That is what I thought, the only one who in my opinion understood the question gets modded down. Odd.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:-

```
function camel(array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a => $b)
    {
    $a  = lcfirst(str_replace(" ", "", ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $a))));
    $GLOBALS[$a] = $b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here they would be available outside the current scope. But I don't think extract put's the items in the global scope. The effect would be (mostly) the same. But now these variables "float around" even when the method that called 'camel' is completed.

Comment: If you want it to be like that, you can use this :-
`function camel(array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a => $b)
    {
    $a  = lcfirst(str_replace(" ", "", ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $a))));
    ${$a} = $b;
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can (cautiously) use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
function camelExtract($vals = array()) {
    foreach ($vals as $key => $v) {
        $splitVar = explode('_', $key);
        $first = true;
        foreach ($splitVar as &$word) {
            if (!$first) {
                $word = ucfirst($word);
            }
            $first = false;
        }
        $key = implode('', $splitVar);
        global ${$key};
        ${$key} = $v;
    }
}
```

This has now been tested and functions as expected. [This condensed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26244125/1188035) (after it addressed the lowercase first word) also works great and is much more condensed - mine is just a little more of a "step by step" to work through how the camel is done.

Comment: Aa, variable variables seem to be a possibility here. However won't you still have the point that those variable variables are only visible within the scope of camelExtract? This is not the case if you use extract. That creates new variables in the scope where it is called from. Not it's own scope.

Comment: @Matthijn I've made an edit that addresses that using the `global` declaration

Comment: That might work indeed, but extract doesn't pollute the global scope as far as I know. But this is a close replication, with global scope pollution that is.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $arr = array('foo_bar'=>'smth');
    function camelExtract($arr) {
        foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
            $newName = lcfirst(str_replace(" ","",ucwords(str_replace("_"," ",$k))));
            global $$newName;
            $$newName = $v; 
            //var_dump($newName,$$newName);
        }
    }
    camelExtract($arr);
    ?>
```

or just like (t's what you suggest, and better to mimic the original extract)

```
$camelArray[lcfirst(str_replace(" ","",ucwords(str_replace("_"," ",$k))))] = $v;
```

and extract on the resulting camelArray

Comment: Yes, but here the new variables are only available in the camelExtract function scope. Extract creates those variables in the scope where it is called from.